# How can we invoke one component from another component with in same repo of stencils

Tags: javascript, stenciljs, stencils

I have one component with

```
render() { 
  return (
    <Host>
      <my-component>
        <button onclick={}></button>
      </my-component>
    </Host>
  );
}
```

How can i invoke `my-component1` from `my-component` based on button-click event and pass some parameter?

I have another component

```
render() { 
  return (
    <Host>
      <my-component1></my-component1>
    </Host>
  );
}
```

Tried calling `my-component1` in `onClick` function. did not work

Comment: Have you looked into `props`?

Comment: Also `Render()` looks suspiciously like React, not Angular as tagged?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by "How can i invoke my-component1 from my-component based on button-click event and pass some parameter?"? Do you want to call a function in the class that defines `my-component1`? Or show `my-component1` when that click handler is invoked? Right now, there isn't a clear connection between the two components, which makes it hard to help :-)